# How to read Apache Storm topology Results

Tags: visualization, apache-storm, topology

I'm new in Apache Storm and I installed in my Windows 8 successfully. I started the topology WordCount locally to test it and it worked fine. However, I want to know what are the words? and what are their counts exactly? and so, Where can I read such  a result?

Also, is there a possibility to visualize  these results?

Please help..

Comment: You can get your data from topology with a [DRPC call](https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Distributed-RPC.html) and do with them whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you Lukas for answering my Question and for the link..